# Android App: Why isn't my update password working?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have my login activity working, but I can't seem to update the user's password after logging in. When I do so, it gives the password failed toast. I think the issue might be that the `currentUser` variable has not been defined in this script, but I'm not sure since I am fairly new to Android dev.

```
package com.example.testapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class UpdatePassword : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    private lateinit var passwordEt: EditText

    private lateinit var changePasswordBtn: Button
    private lateinit var back: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_password)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        passwordEt = findViewById(R.id.password_edt_text)

        changePasswordBtn = findViewById(R.id.reset_pass_btn)
        back = findViewById(R.id.back_btn)

        back.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }

        changePasswordBtn.setOnClickListener{
            var password: String = passwordEt.text.toString()
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                auth.currentUser?.updatePassword(password)
                    ?.addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Password changes successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                            finish()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "password not changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a task fails, there's an exception that you can inspect to find out the cause of the failure. I recommend logging it:

```
auth.currentUser?.updatePassword(password)
    ?.addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password changes successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            finish()
        } else {
            Log.e("updatePassword", "error", task.exception)
            Toast.makeText(this, "password not changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
```

Comment: This gives an error underlining "exception": 

Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: required: String! found: Exception?

"Exception?" is in red coloring.

Comment: Ah, it looks like `e` requires 3 parameters. Updated, but I also **highly** recommend reading the [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) if you get an error like that to see what parameters a method expects.

Comment: I actually changed the line to `Log.e("updatePassword", task.getException().toString())` and it worked (sort of). I started tinkering around with it after posting that comment. Thanks!